# How to make getBytes() with US-ASCII return negative?

Tags: java

I'm currently writing tests for code that executes this command: 
    input.getBytes("US-ASCII")
where input is the input string.

In the interest of providing full coverage, I need to make this method return a negative number for at least one of the bytes that is returned, but I haven't yet found an input that will cause this behavior. What should I feed into the method to make it return a negative byte?

Comment: If you insist.. [Mock it](http://mockito.org/).

Comment: you can't by definition.  ascii values are in the range 0-127.

Comment: There is no such thing as "negative byte"

Comment: @alfasin - in java bytes are signed.

Comment: @jtahlborn nope. There is a signed and unsigned integer. No such thing as signed byte though.

Comment: @alfasin - sorry.  in java, that is not true: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html (all number types except char are signed).

Comment: @jtahlborn as the link says , byte is signed , char is not , char range is from 0 to /uffff

Comment: @jtahlborn true, number are signed. Bytes are not. If you can find the term "signed byte" in the link you posted - please show it to me. "Signed" or "Unsigned" is describing the leftmost *bit*. And it's used to describe negative/positive numbers.

Comment: @alfasin - sorry, did you read the link?  "byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit *signed* two's complement integer."

Comment: @alfasin *"The integral types are byte, [...], whose values are 8-bit, [...] signed two's-complement integers"* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2 I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Guys, read through... Byte is not signed/unsigned. The leftmost *bit* in the byte is used to describe negative/positive *Integers*. Byte has nothing to do with it. There is no such thing as "negative byte" - there is such thing as "negative integer". Integer is represented by two bytes. The leftmost bit is the signed **bit**. Byte by itself has nothing to do with **positive** or **negative** values - it can represent different things. A combination of *two bytes* represents a number or a character. Again - there is no such thing as positive or negative byte.

Comment: @alfasin I'm failing to see how that's a useful distinction. The specification literally says byte is a signed integer of the range -128 to +127. Is a byte with the value -1 not a negative byte? Or do you think it would only be accurate to say it's the binary value 11111111?

Comment: @alfasin - i'm not sure if you're trolling at this point, but try this: `System.out.println("This is a byte " + (byte)0xFF);`

Comment: @Radiodef the OP talks about "US-ASCII" which are characters. There is no such thing as a negative character. Does that make it clear now ?

Comment: @alfasin - sorry again, OP is encoding the characters as bytes (see `getBytes()`).

Comment: @jtahlborn no I'm not trolling - I have better things to do on Sunday morning. I already repeated my self a couple of time. If it's not clear yet - you can stay with signed bytes. Have a great day!

Comment: @Radiodef yes, it's accurate to say that it has s the binary value 11111111. Exactly! This binary value can represent different things, one of them is a number.

Comment: A byte is collection of bits. It is just that, bits. It has no concept of sign. The concept of sign comes when those bits are interpreted as data.

Comment: @gfelisberto exactly! signed/unsigned is used only when interpreting a byte as an integer. It's meaningless when discussing characters (which are also represented by two bytes - same as ints, which is the source of confusion - I guess). Would you consider any *String* as positive or negative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no String that will give you what you want because US-ASCII only includes 0 to 127: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html.

Comment: So I am to take it that full coverage of the method I'm testing is impossible. Well, I guess that happens. Thank you.